# Erratum in A First Course in Abstract Algebra for isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

I don't really know where to post this but, I think I found an erratum in John Fraleigh's book: "A First Course in Abstract Algebra". On page 29, Definition 3.7, Fraleigh defines an isomorphism in such terms:

> Let $\langle S, \star \rangle$ and $\langle S^{'}, \star^{'} \rangle$ be binary algebraic structures. An **isomorphism of** $S$ with $S^{'}$ is a one-to-one function $\phi$ mapping $S$ onto $S^{'}$ such that: $\phi(x \star y) = \phi(y) \star^{'} \phi(y)$ for all $x, y \in S$

Now, I've looked [here](https://www.csustan.edu/sites/default/files/MATH/Jue/4530errata.pdf) at the list of errata for the 7th edition and while there is one on page 29, it doesn't relate to the definition. However, surely the definition is meant to say $\phi(x) \star^{'} \phi(y)$ instead of $\phi(y) \star^{'} \phi(y)$ right?

Comment: Yep, it's a definite typo. Also note that there is a [second unofficial errata sheet](https://gab.wallawalla.edu/~thomth/463/FraleighAbstractAlgebraErrors.pdf).

Comment: Yes, I think so (b.t.w.  *errata* is a plural –  singular is *erratum*).

Comment: Cool thanks! Funny how this one is also not present on the unofficial one. I would have presumed that definition, being a very important part of mathematics, would be check twice.

Comment: @DatCorno Typos are hard to avoid sometimes. And you have a typo yourself:"would be check twice".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's an obvious typo so adds no value to the site.

Answer (score 0):

Does anyone know of an errata sheet for the 8th edition?  On page 53, in the section on subgroups, Theorem 5.15 reads: "A nonempty subset $H$ of the group $G$ is a subgroup of $G$ if and only if for all $a,b \in G$, $ab^{-1}\in G$", but I think this should read
"A nonempty subset $H$ of the group $G$ is a subgroup of $G$ if and only if for all $a,b \in H$, $ab^{-1}\in H$", as this was problem 45 in the 7th edition.

Comment: Hi Joshua, this is certainly a fair question, but this really is a *comment*, not an answer, and so it should go in the comments section. Just book-keeping

Comment: When writing answers, make sure that you do not ask more questions. If you want to ask a question, put it in the comments section.